# SQL: Like '%' + NULL + '%' - what will match to this?

Tags: sql, null, sql-like

I have this code:

```
where (object like
(case when df.RuleType = 'Contains' then '%' + df.[Pattern A] + '%' end)
And object like
(case when df.RuleType = 'Contains' then '%' + df.[Pattern B] + '%' end)
OR object in (case when df.RuleType = 'Equals' then df.[Pattern A] end))
```

In some cases, the input 'Pattern B' will be NULL. How will SQL handle this? How I would like it to be handled is that if object contains Pattern A and Pattern B is null, then the where clause returns true (assuming RuleType is also contains). If RuleType is equals, it just skips to the OR bit and if object is exactly the same as Pattern A it returns True.

However, I am not getting all the output I would expect if SQL was handling it this way (some entries that should return TRUE aren't).

Comment: `LIKE '%something%'` is a bad idea in the first place. Do some research on full-text indexing, especially if you're using sql server.

Comment: NULL will match nothing (including another NULL). NULL is an unknown value, and something unknown can never match something else unknown. (If you can match them, they can't be unknown values, and NULL is an unknown value.) Think of this: Pick two random people off the street, ask them each to go away for 2 miniutes and return with something concealed in their right hands, and then without knowing what each has hidden determine if they're the same. You can't, because one might be holding a coin and the other a stone (or both coins, or both stones). The test for equality can't be done.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn From reading a few pages, it seems the thing wrong with it is query-time (and my query runs in decent time, and is a one-time thing). Is this true or am I missing something that will effect the results?

Comment: If you have good performance now, and this is going away, then it's okay. The problem with `LIKE '%something'` is that normal indexes _will not work at all_, and you're stuck doing full table scans of potentially large values. There is literally _nothing_ you can do in a database that will kill performance faster as your data grows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(case when df.RuleType = 'Contains' then '%' + ISNULL(df.[Pattern A], object) + '%' end)
```

However this is not a particularly wonderful way - but I suspect it will work albeit with performance issues as already commented.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle like this;

```
where ((df.[Pattern A] is NULL OR object like
(case when df.RuleType = 'Contains' then '%' + df.[Pattern A] + '%' end))
And (df.[Pattern B] is NULL OR object like
(case when df.RuleType = 'Contains' then '%' + df.[Pattern B] + '%' end))
OR df.[Pattern A] is NULL OR object in (case when df.RuleType = 'Equals' then df.[Pattern A] end))
```

Some optimization is required